# React JS - how use/change states or function with imported Components

Tags: reactjs

I'm new in ReactJS and the big question is... Is it a good idea divide the solution in other files to organize the code? I think this is better than a lot of components in the same file, but, divide in files this brings one big problem, how use/change the states or functions between this files?

File Index.jsx

```
// index.jsx
Import SecondComponent from '/Components/SecondComponent.jsx'

class FirtstComponent extends React.Component {
    state = {
        mystate: false
    }
}
```

File SecondComponent.jsx

```
// SecondComponent.jsx
class SecondComponent extends React.Component {
    setState = ({
        this.setState({ mystate: true })
    })
}
```

> How can i change the state of the **FirstComponent** from the
>   **SecondComponent**?

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand the question, could you elaborate some more?

Comment: you should provide an example. In most codebases there is only one component per file leading to hundreds or thousands of files and state changes are managed by passing state and update functions through props

Comment: You question is how to update states from different components?

Comment: No, i know that in the same file i can for example create a function in one component and usa this function in another, but if i use a separated file this simple is not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure what you are asking, but I think what you want is something like this:

```
*FirstComponent.jsx*
class FirtstComponent extends React.Component {
    state = {
        mystate: false
    }

    const myFunction = () => {
        this.setState({ mystate: true })
    }

    render() {
      return (
        <SecondComponent function={myFunction} />
      )
    }
}

*SecondComponent.jsx*
export default class SecondComponent extends React.Component {
    render() {
      return (
        <div onClick={this.props.function} />
      )
    }
}
```